# Conditional tasks in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to create an hierarchical task structure. Since this project has over 100tasks as of now, we need to simplify its structure by using "sub-tasks" or `input`s as its called in vs code to gain more visibility over our tasks.

Consider this example (code provided below for this):

```
Run Task -> option(s) --> sub-options 
            option    --> sub-options
```

What I would ideally want is:

```
Run "myTask" -> option(s) --> sub-options based on previous
                          |
                          |--> sub-options based on previous
                          | 
                          |--> sub-options based on previous
```

Lets say I choose `Run Task -> Option1 -> avaliable sub-options for option1`

I want to conditionally see the options for the "parent".

A real world scenario:

```
[Build Customer] Task -> CustomerName  -> Avaliable products for customer
                      -> CustomerName2 -> Avaliable products for customer2
```

> tasks.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "myTask",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": ".\\AutoBuild.bat",
      "options": {
        "shell": {
          "executable": "powershell.exe"
        },
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      },
      "args": [
        "${input:myArg1}",
        "${input:myArg2}"
      ], 
      "group": "build",
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "type": "pickString",
      "id":"myArg1",
      "options": [
        "option1",
        "option2",
        "option3",
        "option4"
      ],
      "description": "myArg1",
      "default": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "pickString",
      "id":"myArg2",
      "description": "myArg2",
      "options": [
        "sub-option1",
        "sub-option2",
        "sub-option3",
        "sub-option4"
      ],
      "default": ""
    },
  ]
}
```

Is this possible to achieve somehow?

*Ugly* or proof of concept solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are no conditional properties for extensions like [keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)' "when". The work around is to execute a script file where input can be acted on. For instance:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "myTask",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": ".\\AutoBuild.bat",
      "args": [
        "${input:myArg1}",
        "${input:myArg2}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`AutoBuild.bat` would then have logic to test and act on `myArg1` and `myArg2`.

Comment: This is unfortunately not an answer to the question.

Comment: There is value in knowing that one cannot do conditionals within `tasks.json`.

Comment: I mean, what you're suggesting in terms of code, i've already provided.

Comment: Fair statement. I guess this just confirms that tasks shouldn't be doing too much.